# What's the difference between 12.04.1 LTS and 12.04.2 LTS?

Tags: 12.04

Just what the title is. I'm wondering what the difference is.

Comment: 12.04.2 contains updates to 12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04.1/2 is just a release of the 12.04 LTS version with upgrades applied (fixes and improvements) since the official release. If you install a 12.04 or 12.04.1 version and you update all the packages, you get the same version as the ISO published.